# Usage of Sinatra in Small-Medium apps

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is Sinatra being used for medium-large sized web applications (not just for small apps)?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read the answers to this question: [Sinatra success stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545254/sinatra-success-stories).

Answer (score 0):

It's best for small aps. It's possible to write medium-large apps in it too, but I'd rather use rails 2.3 for that.